How I query Athena for getting traffic sum
SELECT
  date_trun('minute', from_iso8601_timestamp(time)) - interval '1' minute * (minute(from_iso8601_timestamp(time)) % 5) AS time_group,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(request_url, 'https?://([^/]+)/') AS domain,
  SUM(received_bytes) AS total_received_bytes,
  SUM(sent_bytes) AS total_sent_bytes
FROM alb_access_logs
GROUP BY time_group, REGEXP_EXTRACT(request_url, 'https?://([^/]+)/')
ORDER BY time_group, domain

I would like to get every 5 minutes traffic sum with Amazon Athena.
However, I encountered error as images.
Can you help how I get every 5mins sum traffic?
Thank you in advance.
As below sample statics:

Thank you in advance again.

Please do not add data/code/errors as images - add them as text.

Also, it is hard to understand what do you mean by "error" on the image. You could provide an example of what you'd like to see as a result.
